# Split elements at a value delimiter in vector R

Tags: r, vector, split

I am trying to split a vector at a certain value delimiter. 
I have the following vector: `v <- c("A", "B", "C","-" ,"D", "E", "F")`
Let's say for this example, the  value delimiter is: '-'.

What I want is to obtain several vectors as many as this vector contain this delimiter, since I don't know how many of them are in there. In this example, the results I want should be two vectors **v1** and **v2** and the output would be like:

```
> v1
[1] "A" "B" "C"
```

and

```
> v2
[1] "D" "E" "F"
```

Is there a method or package that does this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `cumsum` on the logical vector and then do the `split` in to `list` of `vector`s.

```
lst <- split(v[v!='-'], cumsum(v=="-")[v!='-'])
names(lst) <- paste0("v", seq_along(lst))
```

If we need it as `vector` objects, use `list2env` (not recommended though)

```
list2env(lst, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Or otherwise, we can directly create `vector` objects in the global environment

```
i1 <- v=="-"
i2 <- v!= "-"
grp <- cumsum(i1)
v1 <- v[i2 & grp==0]  
v2 <- v[i2 & grp == 1]
```